# Automate package installs with Chef on Windows

Tags: windows, automation, installation, chef-infra

I'm new to the Chef world, and I'm trying to come up with a solution to automate the installation of a few programs.  I've found that installers can be run with the **windows_package** command, but that seems to only provide automation when the installer has a silent option.  Is there a way to provide a series of clicks or a list of the buttons that should be pressed during the installation to automate those installers that do not have a silent mode.

Comment: I retitled your question because Automate is also the name of a Chef product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing specifically in Chef for this. You would have to use a tool that does this like AutoIt. Chef can run AutoIt, but it doesn't implement those features itself.